# How to add a custom response header to a function implements actix_web::Responder

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have this function using a broadcaster for SSEs and need to add a custom response header, how can I do that?

```
#[get("/api/sse")]
pub(super) async fn sse(req: HttpRequest, broadcaster: Data<Broadcaster>) -> impl Responder {
    let mut subscribed_events = HashSet::new();

    let args = req.query_string().split("&");
    for arg in args {
        match arg.split_once("=") {
            None => {}
            Some((k, v)) => {
                if k == "event" {
                    subscribed_events.insert(v.to_string());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    broadcaster.new_client(subscribed_events).await
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Responder` trait has a [`customize()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Responder.html#method.customize) function for this:

```rust
use actix_web::{Responder, http::StatusCode, test::TestRequest};

let responder = "Hello world!"
    .customize()
    .with_status(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)
    .insert_header(("x-hello", "world"));

let request = TestRequest::default().to_http_request();
let response = responder.respond_to(&request);
assert_eq!(response.status(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST);
assert_eq!(response.headers().get("x-hello").unwrap(), "world");
```

(Example copied from linked docs)

Comment: I have found this as well but I don't know how to turn my code into a custom responder. Maybe you can add this as well.